# При использовании Multiprocessing, Python не завершает MainProcess

Tags: python, linux, многопоточность

Система UbuntuServer 16.04 LTS

После запуска:

root@webserv:/home/user#python3 script.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys
import signal

def main():
    name = mp.current_process().name
    print(name+' Starting')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.freeze_support()
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    p_main = mp.Process(target=main)
    p_main.start()
    p_main.join()
    print('Скрипт завершает работу')

    print(p_main, p_main.is_alive())
    #<Process(Process-1, stopped)> False

    print(mp.current_process().name)
    #MainProcess

    sys.exit()
```

И скрипт уходит в режим вечного ожидания.

Кто сталкивался? Вроде всё по инструкции с офиц. сайта.
Может конечно дело в Linux и Python, но даже не знаю в какую сторону смотреть.

UPD: Скрипт завершается, если закомментировать p_main.join(). Но это приводит к неправильной работе.

UPD: Если я добавляю в конец процесса (т.е. убиваю его принудительно после завершения логики)

```
    os.killpg(mp.current_process().pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

то всё отрабатывает. Вывод: процессы сами не завершаются.

Comment: Могу предположить, что проблема кроется в том, что в функции `main` есть как-либо блокирующий код, который выполняется бесконечно. Что-то типа "while True". Собственно, указанный выше пример работает вполне нормально, поскольку функция отрабатывает весь код и нормально выходит

Comment: На **Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS**  и **Python 3.5.2** - выше приведенный код работает как и ожидалось: `Process-1 Starting` -> `Скрипт завершает работу` -> `<Process(Process-1, stopped)> False` -> `MainProcess`

Comment: Как Вы видите, в main нет никакого блокирующего кода. Там только вывод имени выполняемого процесса. Это скорее всего особенность ОС Ubuntu Server, и интерпретатора Python для него. Как написано в оф. документации, процессы после выполнения должны завершаться сами и передавать управление в основной. Но в Linux мне приходится в конце кода каждого процесса убивать его принудительно. Вопрос скорее больше к особенностям Python. Нормально ли это, нет ли угрозы утечки памяти и как решать данную проблему. P.S. Я проверил работу данного скрипта на Windows, и там всё работает без завершающего кода.

Comment: В том то всё и дело, что сообщение "MainProcess" есть, но я ожидаю после этого получить доступ к консоли, а вместо этого бесконечное ожидание. Если убить дочерний процесс принудительно после выполнения, то основной процесс завершается и интерпретатор передаёт управление Linux. Если я ставлю код принудительного завершения только в конец основного процесса, то выводится сообщение о "трёх утёкших семафорах". У Вас так же отрабатывает?

Comment: Нет, у меня код нормально выходит обратно в консоль, убунта тоже серверная. К слову, единственное, что я изменил - заменил `import os` на `import sys`

Comment: Yaroslav, спасибо за помощь. Для тестового примера чистил импорты и случайно удалил sys вместо os. В шапке поправил. Но при подключённом sys проблема не пропала. Судя по тому, что у Вас проблема отсутствует, попробую установить Ubuntu Server на тестовом стенде.

Comment: код в вопросе работает как есть (запустился, вышел) на Ubuntu 16.04 (`python -mplatform` -> `Linux-4.4.0-96-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial`, `python3 -V` -> Python 3.5.2)